# Speed and hanging issues in Microsoft Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2007 to download mails from my Yahoo Business Mail account using IMAP. Mail downloading is working fine, and Yahoo's technical team confirmed that Yahoo supports IMAP.

However, Outlook hangs quite frequently and responds after a really long time. I have searched on google, and applied the solutions like disabling Add-Ins.

My PST file size is only 75 MB.

What could be the issue? My operating system is Windows XP Service Pack 3. Outlook version is 2007 (12.0.4518.1014) MSO(12.0.6514.5000)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep everything in your main Inbox folder, try creating some sub-folders and moving all your mail there. Outlook's performance seems to drop off sharply if the root Inbox folder contains too many items.

Comment: I have already about 15-20 folders, out of which I have subscribed to around 5-6 folders. The root Inbox folder only contains mail from 1-Jan-2013. I have moved earlier mails to different folders, and as I said the PST file size is not too much.

Answer (score 0):

These are some things to try:

- Try setting the Send / Receive Settings to initially only download headers.
- Check you have no Virus Scanners integrated with Outlook and actively Scanning the IMAP account. (You might notice Antivirus using CPU)
- As mentioned above subscribing to specific folders rather than all.
- Running Outlook without extensions 'outlook /noextensions'. (Sounds like you have already tried but for the benefit of others)
- Recreate the Imap account.